# Load Balancing job queue among disproportionate workers

Tags: load-balancing, job-scheduling, beanstalkd

I'm working on a tool to automatically manage a job queue (in this case, Beanstalkd).  Currently, you must manually set the number of available workers to pull jobs off the queue, but this does not allow for spikes in jobs, or it wastes resources during low job times.

I have a client/server set up that runs on the job queue server and the workers.  The client connects to the server and reports available resources (CPU/Memory) as well as what types of jobs it can run.  The server then monitors queues and dictates to the connected clients how many workers to run to process that queue once a second. There are currently a hundred or so different worker types and they all use very different amounts of CPU/memory, and the worker servers themselves have different levels of performance.

I'm looking for techniques to balance the workload most effectively based on job queue length and the resource requirement of each worker - for example, some workers use 100% of a core for 5s, while others take microseconds to complete. Also, some jobs are higher priority than others.